# How to run react native app on real android device?

Tags: android, react-native

**I tried to run my app on an android device, but I got this error after usign
npx react-native run-android in my vscode terminal:**

PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProgram\ReactN\my-app> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 2 workers...
info Starting JS server...
"adb" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
..............10%...............20%...............30%...............40%...............50%...............60%...............70%...............80%...............90%...............100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Toolchain support for Scala
- More cache hits when Java source files have platform-specific line endings
- More resilient remote HTTP build cache behavior

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your
> project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProgram\ReactN\my-app\android\local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan
  to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 2m 53s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your
> project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProgram\ReactN\my-app\android\local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan
  to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 53s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProgram\ReactN\my-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProgram\ReactN\my-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProgram\ReactN\my-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewProgram\ReactN\my-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your React-native Project -> Android
Create a file local.properties
Open the file
paste your Android SDK path like below

```
in Windows sdk.dir = C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
in macOS sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
in linux sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk
```

Replace USERNAME with your user name

Now, Run the react-native run-android in your terminal.